# How do I resize things in the interface builder on Xcode 4.5?

Tags: xcode

I recently downloaded Xcode 4.5 (Developer Preview) and have noticed that when you drag something in, you can't resize it by clicking and dragging the edges of the element you have dragged in. How do I resize my UITextView?

EDIT: It was just constraints (part of Xcode 4.5) that were getting in my way. It's all okay now, thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: Xcode 4.5 is still covered by Apple's NDA.

Comment: I`m facing same question , do you have solution now ?

Comment: @Wangchao0721 I've solved it. The constraints were getting in my way. They're pretty annoying. I wonder if there's a way to turn them off...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Interface Builder Go to:
Interface Builder ->Simulated Metrics ->Size - > Freeform

You will now be able to resize the view.

@Mustafa Ahmedani - you can turn off constraints by : Interface Builder ->File Inspector ->Interface Builder Document -> Use AutoLayout (uncheck).

P.S: Also please upvote. Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm blind?  What do you mean by "Interface Builder->Sim..." - I don't see any pulldown menus or prefs panel like that. I am running the full version from the App store.

Comment: It's the first heading under the attributes inspector when you are selecting the View, look into this pic right top part: http://www.techotopia.com/images/2/26/Iphone_ios6_simulated_metrics.png

Comment: Yes, So go to your .xib file on xcode 4.5, then open the _'Attribute Inspector'_ in the right navigation there you should see _'Simulated Metrics'_, goto _'Size'_ and change it to _'Freeform'_.

Answer (score 0):

If you install the full version of 4.5, now available in the app store, it should work fine.